# Gcd of linear function

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, divisors

$\DeclareMathOperator\gcd{gcd}$Take $q\in \mathbb N$ and $X>0$ ($q$ not necessarily smaller than $X$).  A sum such as
$$\sum_{d\leq X}(q,d)$$
is easily seen to be $\ll q^\epsilon (X+q)$ so that the gcd doesn't make the sum much larger than how it would be without it — the values for which $(q,d)$ are significant are rare.

If I have instead a sum like
$$\sum_{dd'\leq X}(q,d+d')$$
can I still conclude a similar bound, thinking that the $d+d'$ should give just as "random values" to $(q,d+d')$ as did $d$ to $(q,d)$? Or is this completely the wrong way to think about it?

It's of course similar to asking about
$$\sum_{\substack{dd'\leq X\\q\mid d+d'}}1$$
which seems easy enough but I'm still a bit unsure… is this even $\ll (qX)^\epsilon (X/q+1)$?

Comment: Which definition of $\ll$ are you using here? I'm used to seeing it to mean something approximating little-o notation, but for $q = 2$, the sum is around $\frac{3}{2} X$, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: If $q = \prod p_i^{n_i}$ is held constant, then the first sum is approximately $\prod (1 + \frac{p_i - 1}{p_i} n_i) X$ for large $X$. There may be few significant large contributors, but if the number of contributors is comparable to $X$, then that can be a large contribution on its own.

Comment: $\ll $ means the usual one ($X\ll Y $ if $|X|<CY$, for some positive $C$).

Comment: hmm not sure about your second comment (if $q$ is constant then the gcd is irrelevant given the bounds i'm trying for. are you sure that's what you mean or maybe i misunderstood?

Comment: I probably should have written $X \prod (1 + \frac{p_i - 1}{p_i} n_i)$ for clarity, but otherwise yes. And that also should disprove the assertion if we instead let $q$ grow: consider $q_i = X_i = 2^i$; then the sum is $(1 + \frac{i}{2}) X$, which is eventually larger than $C (X + q)$ for any $C$.

Comment: i don't think i understand this index formula.  however, in any case, $iX$ isn't larger than $q^\epsilon (X+q)$

Comment: If that's what you meant by "thinking of $q^\epsilon$ bounds as harmless", then I didn't find it clear; I think it's worth rewriting that for clarity. If that is what you meant, then you shouldn't need to add $q$ to $X$ in the first place, I think.

Comment: ok, edited.  i think i still need the $q$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.** We have
$$\sum_{\substack{dd'\leq X\\q\mid d+d'\\d\leq d'}}1
=\sum_{d\leq\sqrt{X}}\sum_{\substack{d'\leq X/d\\q\mid d+d'\\d\leq d'}}1
\leq\sum_{d\leq\sqrt{X}}\sum_{\substack{c\leq 2X/d\\q\mid c}}1
\leq\sum_{d\leq\sqrt{X}}\frac{2X}{qd}<\frac{2X(1+\log\sqrt{X})}{q}.$$
We get the same bound when the roles of $d$ and $d'$ are interchanged,
hence in the end
$$\sum_{\substack{dd'\leq X\\q\mid d+d'}}1<\frac{2X(2+\log X)}{q}\ll_\epsilon\frac{X^{1+\epsilon}}{q}.$$

**2.** From the last inequality we infer
$$\sum_{dd'\leq X}(q,d+d')\leq
\sum_{r\mid q}r\sum_{\substack{dd'\leq X\\r\mid d+d'}}1
\ll_\epsilon\sum_{r\mid q}r\frac{X^{1+\epsilon}}{r}\ll_\epsilon (qX)^\epsilon X.$$

Comment: top! thanks a lot! ^ ^